# Ember.js bower AdminLTE dependencies

Tags: ember.js, bower, ember-cli, adminlte

Im learning Ember.js and I want to create a simple [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) + [AdminLTE](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE) app. I did following steps:

1. `$ ember new app`
2. `$ cd app`
3. `$ bower install admin-lte`
4. `$ ember build --env production`

My questions:

1. Why there is no AdminLTE dependency in bower.json ?
2. Why there is no AdminLTE CSS and JS in compiled assets ?
3. Do I have to manually add some dependencies to "ember-cli-build.js" file ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Because you need to run bower install with --save parameter in order to update bower.json. The same can be told about npm.
2. Because 3.
3. Yes, there is a [guide](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#managing-dependencies)